# Change IP address dynamically?

Tags: web-scraping, ip, web-crawler, scrapy, dynamic-ip

Consider the case, 
I want to crawl websites frequently, but my IP address got blocked after some day/limit.

So, how can change my IP address dynamically or any other ideas?

Answer (score 53):

An approach using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) will make use of two components, `RandomProxy` and `RotateUserAgentMiddleware`.

Modify `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` as follows. You will have to insert the new components in the `settings.py`:

```python
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'tutorial.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
    'tutorial.spiders.rotate_useragent.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' :400,    
}
```

### Random Proxy

You can use [`scrapy-proxies`](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies). This component will process Scrapy requests using a random proxy from a list to avoid IP ban and improve crawling speed.

You can build up your proxy list from a quick internet search. Copy links in the `list.txt` file according to requested url format.

### Rotation of user agent

For each scrapy request a random user agent will be used from a list you define in advance:

```python
class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):
        self.user_agent = user_agent

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(self.user_agent_list)
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)

            # Add desired logging message here.
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request),
                level=log.DEBUG
            )

    # the default user_agent_list composes chrome,I E,firefox,Mozilla,opera,netscape
    # for more user agent strings,you can find it in http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php
    user_agent_list = [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.0 Safari/536.6",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1090.0 Safari/536.6",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.77.34.5 Safari/537.1",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.36 Safari/536.5",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1063.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.0 Safari/536.3",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24"
    ]
```

More details [here](https://gist.github.com/seagatesoft/e7de4e3878035726731d).

Comment: Thanks for the solution that helps me a lot. Can you please elaborate the role of DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES here. @aberna

Comment: In the RotateUserAgentMiddleware, only one  useragent is assigning for a spider, i.e, I am crawling with recursive calls, for every call I wanted to change the  User-Agent with is not happening with the above code. Please help me out.

Comment: how to get the proxy list? anybody? help

Comment: Have you tried to search on google for "free proxy list" ?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using R, you could do the web crawling through TOR. I think TOR resets its IP-adress every 10 minutes(?) automatically. I think there is a way forcing TOR to change the IP in shorter intervals, but that didn't work for me. Instead you could set up multiple instances of TOR and then switch between the independent instances (here you can find a good explaination of how to set up multiple instances of TOR: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips)

After that you could do something like the following in R (use the ports of your independent TOR browsers and a list of useragents. Every time you call the 'getURL'-function cycle through your list of ports/useragents)

```
library(RCurl)

port <- c(a list of your ports)
proxy <- paste("socks5h://127.0.0.1:",port,sep="")
ua <- c(a list of your useragents)

opt <- list(proxy=sample(proxy,1),
            useragent=sample(ua,1),
            followlocation=TRUE,
            referer="",
            timeout=timeout,
            verbose=verbose,
            ssl.verifypeer=ssl)

webpage <- getURL(url=url,.opts=opt)
```

Answer (score 3):

Some VPN applications allow you to automatically change your IP address to a new random IP address at a set interval such as: every 2 minutes. Both [HMA! Pro VPN](http://www.adeepbite.com/hidemyass-vpn-review/#Schedule_IP_Address_Change) and VPN4ALL software support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Word of warning about VPNs, check their Terms and Conditions carefully because scraping using them goes against their user policy ( One such example would be Astrill). I tried a scraping tool and got my account locked

Answer (score -1):

If you have public IPs. Add them on your interface and if you are using Linux use Iptables for switching those public IPs.

Iptables sample rules for two IPs

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.2

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.3
```

If you have 4 IPs then probablity will become 0.25.

You can also create your own proxy with simple steps.

These rules will allow the proxy server to switch its outgoing IPS.