# Getting error "pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver, pywin32

I am trying to use selenium with python to get latitude and longitude from [this](http://www.whatsmygps.com/) site. I am also using win32lipboard. But whenever I run my code, randomly it throws me this error `pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')`.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import csv
import win32clipboard

csvreader = csv.reader(open("master_data.csv", 'r'))

csvwriter = csv.writer(open('final_master_data.csv', 'w', newline=''))

headers = next(csvreader)
headers.append("latitude")
headers.append("longitude")
csvwriter.writerow(headers)

locations = list(csvreader)

chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.whatsmygps.com')

for places in locations:
    place = places[6] + ", " + places[4] + ", " + places[2]

    location = driver.find_element_by_id("address")

    location.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    location.send_keys(place)

    location.submit()

    time.sleep(3)

    lat_input = driver.find_element_by_id("latitude")
    lat_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    lat_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    lat = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()

    places.append(lat)

    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

    lon_input = driver.find_element_by_id("longitude")
    lon_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    lon_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    lon = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

    places.append(lon)
    print(places)

    csvwriter.writerow(places)

driver.close()
```

so, whenever I run this code, it starts with no issues, it reads csv file and enter location names into this sites and starts to copy latitude and longitude from the site and insert those into another csv file. But after some time, randomly, it throws error `pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')`. I am unable to find the solution about this since yesterday.

**UPDATE**: I am using Anaconda and I am running anaconda shell as an administrator, so there is no issue with the access permission.

Comment: I don't remember but shouldn't `driver.find_element_by_id("address").text` contain the string which you want?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I have used `driver.find_element_by_id("address")` to get the element by the id and if we used `.text` property then we get the text. But this field is input field and in this field using selenium I enter the location address. There is no issue with this I am getting issue when I copy and paste the  latitude and longitude. You may check it by visiting the site itself.

Comment: Okay I got confused. See if you can get directly read `driver.find_element_by_id("latitude").text` and same thing for `longitude`

Comment: I have tried that too. But it doesn't give you anything in this case. It would be great help, if you check it personally. I have given link to the website in my above script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access denied error may occur if clipboard is locked by another process. To avoid python messages, you can use WinAPI version of clipboard as described in this SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23285159/4603670

---

As an alternative, use BingMap which requires API key. As of this writing, you can register a developer account at https://www.bingmapsportal.com for the free API key (I am not sure about the quota).

```
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
import json

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
winhttp = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')

def bing_find_gps(addressLine, postalCode, country):

    q = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key='
    q = q + 'my_api_key'
    if country: q = q + '&countryRegion=' + country
    if postalCode: q = q + '&postalCode=' + postalCode
    if addressLine: q = q + '&addressLine=' + addressLine

    try:
        winhttp.Open('GET', q, False)
        winhttp.Send()
        if not winhttp.responseText:
            return 0
        list = json.loads(winhttp.responseText)
        if list['statusCode'] != 200:
            return 0
        gps = list['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['point']['coordinates']
        if gps:
            return (1, gps[0], gps[1])
    except:
        return 0

res = bing_find_gps('One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA, 98052-6399', '0', 'United States')
if res:
    print("lat/long %s, %s" % (res[1], res[2]))
res = bing_find_gps(0, '98052-6399', 'United States')
if res:
    print("lat/long %s, %s" % (res[1], res[2]))
```

---

Or use [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org):

```
address = "98052-6399" #Testing with Microsoft zip code
url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=" + address
winhttp.Open('GET', url, False)
winhttp.Send()
list = json.loads(winhttp.responseText)
print(list[0].get('lat'))
print(list[0].get('lon'))
```

Expected output:

> ```
> Latitude: 47.670119 
> Longitude: -122.118237
> ```

Or you may also wish to avoid copying the element altogether, use `get_attribute('value')` to read the value in `latitude` and `longitude`. Example:

```
chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.whatsmygps.com')

element = driver.find_element_by_id("address")
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
#enter Microsoft's zip code
element.send_keys('98052-6399')
element.submit()
time.sleep(3)

lat_input = driver.find_element_by_id("latitude")
print('latitude: ')
print(lat_input.get_attribute('value'))

lon_input = driver.find_element_by_id("longitude")
print('longitude: ')
print(lon_input.get_attribute('value'))

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used your solution i.e. `get_attribute('value')` and it worked. I haven't checked the link that you provided but i'll do that later. Thanks once again.

Comment: Note the above website uses Google APIs, the service is not guaranteed (it is currently blocked, it says it reached key owner's maximum quota). You can use Google API directly, but I am not clear what are Google's current terms of service (I think you have to pay). See edit for using free openstreetmap.org instead

Comment: Initially I also thought to use openstreetmap, but in my case, there are many cities for which openstreetmap doesn't provide any data. Example: this is my address: Adojig, Andaman and Nicobar Islands, India. Now if you try to fetch details using openstreetmap, it won't give you any detail but using the site which I mentioned above, it will give you lat and lon. That's why I chose that.

Comment: But as you mentioned that site also restricts the amount of hit after some number of hits. So currently I am thinking to scrap this and use scrapy with their own proxy feature with form filling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852057/change-ip-address-dynamically#answer-28877031 and https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2012/10/26/filling-login-forms-automatically

Comment: I don't recommend using proxies, because it abusive and it probably won't work anyway. Most likely Google sets the quota based on API key. What about using Bing Map?

Comment: Okay, I haven't checked with Bing map. Let me check.

Comment: Maybe you could use all of them. Bing + openstreet + Google. If Bing doesn't work then try another method. See edit.